# How to get entities of type alpha-numeric using DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am creating a Google Action using DialogFlow, I require a user input for which the entity should be of alpha-numeric type(like part-number or order-number).

I have tried the system entity type @sys.flight-number, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be difficult, as Dialogflow is not designed to match alpha-numeric characters. Trying to input a series of letters and numbers can be easily misinterpreted, especially if just being spoken. If you can, I'd recommend not doing  that.

Perhaps the user inputs these characters using an app or website, then the Action will authenticate using Google Sign-In or OAuth and pull the values from your account.

Alternatively, your Dialogflow intent could have a custom alphanumeric entity marked as a list, and let the user input values using the [phonentic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet).